# Google Vision OCR: DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION produces strange results when TEXT_DETECTION is fine

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision

I'm playing around within the quick start guide: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart and I noticed there were wildly different results when using the same image for `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` vs `TEXT_DETECTION`.

For reference, this is the image I'm using (plug this in for `imageUri`):
https://storage.googleapis.com/random-resources/receipt.jpg

When using `TEXT_DETECTION`, the description seems to give a good summary of the image but when I use `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION`, the result is a bunch of text that is found nowhere on the image:

> "OLZ-E\niNO N WHL\nL8' G7 WY NINId\n9E'V\nDG'S\n78' 8\nSD 177\nXel [ 101\n3L VON VW IS\nXVI\n11/ans\nas\na new set \"\nHe same time in more\nS8' 9p\nS8' 9p\n98' 9p\nGD' Ot\nGD'Or\nIIIA AHNIH\nIIIA ANNIH !\nIIIA AHNIH L\nLNI ALII I\nLNI ALII !\nement on to\nSee more money were more women\none more time we came as we are on memo sense we need some more money when we see some moment as a team\nwdE:6\nI Ssang\n200E YOay)\nLL |602 SOL Jed H3NNIS\nNNS\nEEZ a qel\nsame was one or more was a\nmoment\nto earn and a time when\nwe are seen\n909t-G88-9\nOIL 6 PD 'OISION VX: NVS\nINNIZAV SSN NVA 906\nBIY SWINd\nO\nSNOH\n"

Any ideas?

Comment: As of 2019 I can say that my test regarding TEXT_DETECTION vs DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION for receipts similiar to yours, both OCR types work quite well. But the TEXT_DETECTION gives me about 10% better results overall. I think the reason is, the DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION expects well structured documents which are upright and mostly undistorted.